# how to use camera intent in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-camera-intent, onactivityresult

```
public void CAPTURE()
{
    final ListView mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvImage);    

    .... set adapter ... 

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView,final int position,long mylng)
        {               

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            File imagesFolder = new file(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImage");
            imagesFolder.mkdirs();
            filePath = "/MyImage/test.png";
            File image = new File(imagesFolder, "test.png");
            Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) 
    {

        String p = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + filePath;

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(p);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);            
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();


            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ImageActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("image", byteArray);
            intent.putExtra("path", p);

            startActivity(intent);
        }

     }
}
```

i call camera intent when click on items in listview and create folder 
 and file image this is working
 i go to folder and see a image perfectly
 but my onActivityResult not work still be in this activity
 i want to pass path and imagebyte to next activity

i try place finish() at down startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_REQUEST);
but not working

what should i do pls help me. sorry for bad english

thanks a lot

Comment: have u given permission to write external storage ?

Answer (score 0):

**By this method you can upload the image from camera** :

```
Uri myPicture;
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
public void camera_upload()
{

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Media.TITLE, "My demo image");
    values.put(Media.DESCRIPTION, "Image Captured by Camera via an Intent");
    myPicture = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, myPicture);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

}
```

**Also give following permissions in your manifest**:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

**Method to go to next activity**

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Set_theme_Activity.class);
                // passing array index
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
```

**Method to fetch image in activity(NextActivity)**

```
Intent i = getIntent();
        // Selected image id
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageAdaptor imageAdapter = new ImageAdaptor(this);
```

Comment: i know about that but i want to go next activity in onActivityResult man

Comment: after uploading you want to go to next activity?

Comment: i create image in listview when click on items via camera_intent and i want to pass data to upload in next activity but seems like onActivityResult not work

Comment: i use camera intent in listview when click on items but seems onActivityResult not working this my problem

Answer (score 0):

hey you are not extracting data from intent in onactivityresult which you had put in intent in startactivityforresult.